# PHP Session Variable Bug?

Tags: php, session-variables

I have run into a bizare issue with PHP sessions that is driving me nuts.  Here is the gist of what I am doing

```
$tout = time();
session_start();
$_SESSION['dna'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if (1 == $user->demo) 
    $_SESSION['demo'] = $user->demo;
$_SESSION['tout'] = $tout;
```

This appears to work just fine.  However, this variant

```
$tout = time();
session_start();
$_SESSION['dna'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if (1 == $user->demo) 
{
    $_SESSION['demo'] = $user->demo;
    $tout += 900;
} else 
    $tout += 7200;
$_SESSION['tout'] = $tout;
```

trashes the entire $_SESSION array.

Briefly, what I am trying to do is to keep track of when the user session stated on each subsequent interaction with the server establish whether the session should be marked as being timed out and the user informed accordingly.  The timeout should be 900s in demo mode and 7200s otherwise.

Perhaps there is an issue with integer arithmetic on my 32 bit local WAMP server though I doubt it since a simple test script where I do the arithmetic and echo the result works.  That points to some sort of issue with storing the result in the session array.

This is driving me round the bend and I am sure that there is something obvious that I am not seeing here.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you print_r($_SESSION) in last of each code?

Comment: I did some more testing and found some rather strange things. If I don't do any arithmetic on $tout - or do $tout + 0, which I imagine is filtered out by the PHP interpreter as being useless - the session variable is intact.  Any other $tout + N followed by trigger_error(json_encode($_SESSION)) shows the full session array but subsequently letting the session data being written and then attempting to pick it up later in another script returns an empty session array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using dechex($tout + NNN).  on testing further I found that this issue only turned up on my 32 bit WAMP isntallation.  On my 64 bit CentOS server there were no problems.

I have now also figured out what is going wrong.  The default session storage for PHP serializes the $_SESSIONS variable.  The 'tout' element was being treated as an integer, 32 bit, and then the deserialization was failing.

A further note - up until the point where the session is closed and gets serialized the SESSIONS array shows up the right content since PHP silently converts the value to a double.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['tout'] = time();

    $_SESSION['dna'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    if (1 == $user->demo) 
    {
     $_SESSION['demo'] = $user->demo;
     $_SESSION['tout'] = $_SESSION['tout'] + 10 * 60  // for example 10 minutes
    } 
    else 
     $_SESSION['tout'] = $_SESSION['tout'] + 20 * 60  // for example 20 minutes
?>
```

Comment: I have tried all sorts of variations - even rather irrational ones.  As I mentioned in my last comment the issue appears to be not with assigning values to the SESSION array but recovering it later from another script once the session has been written - at that point the entire array comes back empty.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['dna'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if (1 == $user->demo) 
{
 $_SESSION['demo'] = $user->demo;
 $tout = time()+900;
} else $tout = time()+7200;
$_SESSION['tout'] = $tout;
```

Comment: Wolfram : It will increase only from `current time`, not from `user session time`..